# Number of 1s in a binary number

Tags: c, recursion, bit-manipulation

I need to make a program that counts the number of 1s in the binary representation of an unsigned number, using a recursive function, so this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int one(unsigned n);

int main()
{
    unsigned n;
    printf("n= "); scanf("%u", &n);
    printf("%d", one(n));

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int one(unsigned n)
{
    if(n==1 || n==0)
        return n;
    else
        return (n&1+one(n>>1));
}
```

Thing is, my code works for number `7` for example, but if I enter the number `2` it will print that it has `2` ones in it. And for `4` it returns 0, and I think for all exponents of 2 it returns 0 in the end. I can't figure out why.

Comment: First thing I would try is cleaning up your return values and such.  You are returning a signed int, passing in an unsigned something?  So.. ideally, keep everything unsigned when you are doing bitwise manipulation.  You can do it both ways, but it makes it easier to know for sure you are doing what you think you are doing.. if that makes sense.  As part of that, you should printf a %u on both lines.  Let us know if you continue to have a problem after you get all of your arguments into unsigned

Comment: Tried it and same result.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Split your return statement so you do each piece on a separate line and walk through with breakpoints then.  so.. `unsigned x=n&1; unsigned y=one(n>>1); return x+y`

Comment: I just thought I'd mention a neat trick that would reduce the amount of recursion for the average case (but not for the worst case). The trick is to always remove a '1' bit for each step of the recursion, so you're only recursing for '1' bits and not for '0' bits. The trick is as follows: `int one(unsigned n) { if (n) return 1 + one(n & (n - 1)); return 0; }`. The `n & (n - 1)` expression has the value of `n` with the lowest '1' bit removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
    return (n&1+one(n>>1));
```

The addition operator `+` operator has higher precedence that the bitwise-AND operator `&`.  So the expression is effectively:

```
    return (n & ( 1 + one(n >> 1)));
```

You need to add parenthesis around `n&1`:

```
    return ((n & 1) + one(n >> 1));
```

EDIT:

As a programming exercise, this works fine.  In real life code, a precomputed lookup table is much more efficient.

```
// Assumes CHAR_BITS == 8

int numbits[256] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4,
                   ...
                     4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 6, 7, 7, 8 };

int count_bits(unsigned n)
{
    int i, count = 0;
    for (i=0; i<sizeof(n); i++) {
        count += numbits[(uint8_t)(n & 0xFF)];
        n >>= 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance here, considering the speed of *computing* things nowadays, compared to the slowness of memory accesses, but this might depend on caching and the usage pattern, so it's hard to made a definite statement here. In any case, for alternatives, one might want to have a look at the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive), which presents 7 ways of counting the set bits.

Answer (score 2):

The `&` operator has a lesser precedence than the `+` operator, which causes the calculation in the `else` branch or `one` to produce the wrong (logically) result. Just surround it by parenthesis to make sure it's executed first and you should be fine:

```
return (n & 1) + one(n>>1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
return (n&1+one(n>>1));
```

The operator `+` has a higher precedence than `&`. But, you have to mask the last bit first, then add it:

```
return ((n&1) + one(n>>1));
```